# git command to get local path of repository

Tags: git, batch-file, repository

Is there a way to get the path of a local repository from git that can be executed from a batch file?

```
set GITBIN="c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
set REPODIR1=C:\RandomPath1\REPOSITORY1
set REPODIR2=C:\RandomPath2\REPOSITORY2

pushd %TGACOREDIR%

@echo on
%GITBIN%\git pull
        @if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
            goto :pullerror
        )
```

I'd like to get REPODIR1 and REPODIR2 from git, so that developers can run the script, even if they have their local repositories in different locations from one another. Is there a way to do it so that REPODIR1 and REPODIR2 don't have to be hardcoded in this .bat file?

Answer (score 1):

This command should do what you want

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Comment: this will give me the path to the top level of the repository I'm currently in. I'm looking for a way to find all the git repositories on a machine by name.

Comment: Hmm, on unix you just search for hidden .git directories with `find / -type d -name .git`.  The same might work on a PC.  http://superuser.com/questions/401495/equivalent-of-unix-find-command-on-windows